# Setting SSL Cipher Suites in Portal Admin

Tags: arcgis-server, security, arcgis-portal, encryption

I am trying to update the SSL cipher suites (to be in compliance with my org security requirements) at '/portal/portaladmin/security/sslCertificates/update'
according to [this page](http://server.arcgis.com/en/portal/latest/administer/windows/restrict-portal-for-arcgis-ssl-protocols-and-cipher-suites.htm)

I am getting:  Error: One or more invalid HTTPS cipher suites

I have checked and all cipher suites I am using are compatible according to the [linked page](http://server.arcgis.com/en/portal/latest/administer/windows/restrict-portal-for-arcgis-ssl-protocols-and-cipher-suites.htm)

I could not find any information on this issue. Has anyone successfully changed the cipher suites this way?

**EDIT: The cipher suites I want to set:**

TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA

Comment: Are you able to share the cipher suites you want to use?

Comment: added cipher suites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested the cipher suites in my test ArcGIS Server 10.5.1 (by mistake), they worked there. I did encounter the same error you got in Portal 10.5.1. I cut the chase by directly updating the file on disk. The file updated when you change the cipher suites in Portal is located at "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Portal\framework\runtime\tomcat\conf" assuming you installed Portal on C:. It's the "server.xml" file. I backed up mine and then directly added your cipher suites. That was after stopping Portal. It restarted successfully after that. Took a little longer.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. It turns out I actually need to do this on the server machine as well. It doesn't seem to be working for me there. I'm guessing i can try to directly update the config file like you did with portal?

Comment: Yes. For Server, the file should be at "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Server\framework\runtime\tomcat\conf\server.xml". 

Stop the Server, back up the file before you make any changes to the list of ciphers. The Cipher list will be at the bottom of the file.

I updated the answer to include a picture of the Server Ciphers.